# Coldfusion cfmodule slowing page loading time

Tags: jquery, coldfusion

We have a page that returns a list of all our categories with descriptions and names which save to our mysql database.

The only problem is that we require the description field to use fckeditor (to input html) but because we have 160 categories it takes forever to load because it is being included by cfmodule 160 times.

```
<cfmodule template="../fckeditor/fckeditor2.cfm" basePath="../fckeditor/" instanceName="scndctgry_Intro#rsScndCategoryList.CurrentRow#" width="100%" height="100">
```

Is there a good way to call this coldfusion code using a new window on each individual category so it doesn't crash the page? I tried using jquery toggle to hide the div but of course coldfusion still loads the code (stupid!)

Any suggestions/advice would be great.

Thanks

Comment: Why is it necessary to put all 160 text editors on the page at once?

Comment: Yeah, that's a UX nightmare. You should only display all 160 category descriptions IFF there's a chance they'll *all* get used for a given page-imprint. The problem here isn't the performance of the code, it's the undue stress you're putting everything under by having a poorly-designed UI. Revise your UI to remove the clutter, and let the user pick the description they wish to maintain.

Comment: You could (should) simply list the categories and then go to a new page or open a modal window to edit them. That way you only ever have a single text editor on the screen.

Comment: @AdamCameron, what is the file fckeditor/fckeditor2.cfm , that is given for the template field. I am trying to integrate CKEditor4 with ColdFusion 2016, but I could not able to find many details on this, sorry for posting my doubt here.